# Brownie Eth - Changing networks does not change the network.chain.id

Tags: brownie

I am trying to programatically deploy a Smart Contract via Brownie to multiple test networks.

The following code works, however when I switch networks the `network.chain.id` renames the same as the first one. I need this chain_id so I can store the contract addresses that have been deployed for each network.

```
for name in ["fuji-testnet", "polygon-test", "goerli"]:
    network.disconnect()
    network.connect(network_name, launch_rpc=False)
    print(network.show_active(), network.is_connected(), network.chain.id)
```

The above code will output:

fuji-testnet True 43113
polygon-test True 43113
goerli True 43113

Which is not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You will find that this is a bug in `brownie` at the time of writing but you can access the true `chain_id` with

```
brownie.web3.chain_id
```

Comment: thanks guys, took me hours to debug this. who would have thought this bug is still present?